# Will increasing the precision of a column with ALTER affect database performance while executing on bulk data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, alter-table

I have an SQL table in a live database which has more than 6 millions rows and I want to increase the precision of a particular column:

```
ALTER TABLE sales ALTER COLUMN amount DECIMAL(8,4)
```

Now my question is if I execute above query, will SQL Server recalculate each cell and write back new values into same cell? (If yes, that means it will definitely take a long time to execute and our other activities on database will be affected.) Or, will the statement be executed some other way?

Comment: [This might help](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/changing-columns-data-type).  _"Typically, I'd recommend using the ALTER TABLE option, especially if you have only a few thousand rows of data, because this solution doesn't affect permissions. However, using the ALTER TABLE command does impact data availability, so you probably don't want to use it during regular work hours or if you have millions of rows in your table."_

Comment: What is the required availability of the table, is it 24/7 or do you have down time for maintenance? Also, how is the table accessed, directly or via views/stored procedures?

Comment: What is the current type of that column?

Comment: @Tony Ya it is 24/7, and currently we accessing table via view only...!!!!!!

Comment: @wallyk Current type of that column is decimal(8,2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## A quick correction

A conversion of `decimal(8, 2)` to `decimal(8, 4)` isn't actually increasing the *precision*; it's increasing the *scale*.

From [decimal/numeric - TSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187746%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

- **precision** The maximum total number of decimal digits that can be stored, *both to the left and to the right of the decimal point*.
- **scale** The maximum number of decimal digits that can be stored *to the right of the decimal point*. Scale must be a value from 0 through p.

So the overall number of digits (and therefore, storage requirements) have not changed.

## The answer

If you have any value over **9999.9999**, you're going to have a bad time in the form of an arithmetic overflow error. To accommodate all possible (8, 2) values, you would need to increase the column to `decimal(10, 4)` instead.

This, however, will increase the storage requirements for your column, going from 5 to 9 bytes. As a result, this is equivalent to an `update` statement in terms of its impact on availability and the transaction log.

What I have found based on testing, is that for at least SQL Server 2008R2, the increased precision will only incur an update of the data if the storage requirements change. Essentially *if the column's new precision value is in the same storage (or smaller, and no truncation occurs) size category as the previous, then the table data is untouched*.

For a 6-million row table, the impact on the transaction log will be around 2.5GB. It won't necessarily grow by this amount, but that's how much space it will consume. My testing used around 2-million rows, and the `alter` statement caused the logs to grow from 1MB to ~850MB.

As for the impact on performance (how long it will take), without knowing anything about your server's hardware and load it's impossible to say. If you were sufficiently concerned to want to avoid modifying the table in place, your best approach is probably a table swap:

Create a new table (`sales_tmp`) with the desired schema, and copy the data:

```
insert sales_tmp
select * from sales;
```

If you can ensure that the `sales` table won't be modified during the operation, you don't have to worry about preventing it with transactions and locks. Otherwise, a `repeatable read` transaction should suffice, and at least won't block reads to the `sales` table during the operation.

Then:

1. Replicate permissions on the new table
2. Recreate indexes & foreign key references
3. Drop old table
4. Rename new (`sales_tmp` to `sales`)

This can have some issues if you have replication or other fancy things setup on the affected table. Those aren't trivial to disable and re-enable, sadly.

## Transaction log

If you are worried about the impact on the transaction log of updating 6-million records, you will need to update the records in batches. The size of which will vary depending on your needs. I would recommend 1,000-10,000.

IMO, I don't think you really need to worry about this, unless your database server is really strapped for free space, but this information might prove useful for future.

If your recovery model is SIMPLE, so too is log containment. If it is FULL, things are harder.

In spite of what Blam claims in his answer, his loop implementation will *absolutely not* guarantee any containment of the transaction log file.

### SIMIPLE recovery

Issue a `checkpoint` statement at the end of the loop body to ensure log data is flushed. SQL Server periodically does this anyway and in most cases you won't notice, *but in some cases you will*. Below is highly simiplified psudeocode:

```
while @rows_left > 0
begin
    -- update/copy rows
    checkpoint;
end
```

### FULL recovery

This is trickier because the log grows indefinitely until you take a log backup, which marks the log pages as inactive and enables SQL Server to re-use the space already allocated for the log files. I won't go into this in detail, other than to recommend a few resources:

- [Managing the Transaction Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms345382%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [BACKUP (TSQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms186865%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: I agree with explaination as you're said, it is hard job since it is a production server (Live database server) while i swaping data into new table data may became inconsistent....and also we have to re define additional actions which we did on old table (Triggers, Stored_procedures etc..)...Instead of that i feel it is better to go with alter or update

Comment: You can still deal with data consistency by wrapping the statement in a transaction with the appropriate isolation levels. The advantage over `alter table` is that you only need read locks while the data is copying. That means your live table is only blocked for writes and not reads as well.

Comment: This is not a clear situation. For example, changing the size of a variable-length column never updates data. For widening it is a metadata-only change. For narrowing a *read* of the entire column must be performed.

Comment: @usr But a varchar allocates space on the fly.  Pretty sure decimal allocate space up front.

Comment: @Blam the physical representation could be the same for similar precision specifications. This answer is not based on evidence.

Comment: @usr You don't know that it is not based on evidence.  He may have evidence that an alter to a higher precision performs a convert.

Comment: I can't yet find any supporting documentation from Microsoft, but it appears to depend on whether the precision increase causes increased storage requirements. See update in answer.

Comment: See my answer.  A change in scale with the same precision can cause truncation and SQL will throw and error.

Comment: My investigation was more aimed at whether the alter statement would trigger an update of the data, causing log growth and loss of availability. I did neglect to consider the truncation error issue though.

Answer (score 2):

I do not come to the same conclusion/findings as Matt

[decimal and numeric (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

> For the decimal and numeric data types, SQL Server considers each
>   specific combination of precision and scale as a different data type.
>   For example, decimal(5,5) and decimal(5,0) are considered different
>   data types.

(8,4) is a different type from (8,2) and must be cast.

And you are not increasing the precision.  Same precision - different scale.

decimal(8,2) 12356.78 will NOT cast to decimal(8,2).
I tested on a decimal(8,2) column that contained that value SSMS would not let me change it to decimal(8,4)

You will need to go to decimal(10,4) and it will cast / convert

This fails on the set @dec84 = @dec82;

```
declare @dec82 decimal(8,2);
declare @dec84 decimal(8,4);
set @dec82 = 123456.78;
set @dec84 = 1234.5678;
print @dec82;
print @dec84;
set @dec84 = @dec82;
print @dec84;
```

Add a column to the existing table with the proper precision.
No index.
And add it as the last column!
If not the last column it may try and move data around

To protect the transaction log update in batches
100 is just an example

```
update top (100) table 
set newCol = oldCol 
where newCol is null
```

If it is indexed then add that here
Then finish with a

```
update table 
set newCol = oldCol 
where newCol <> oldCol
```

Then rename newCol to oldCol

This is how I do loops to contain the transaction log
Usually in chunks of 10000

```
declare @rowCount Int;
Set @rowCount = 1
While @rowCount > 0
Begin
   update top (1) [test].[dbo].[DateDateTime] 
   set [ddateTimeNoTime] = '2014-11-12'
   where [ddateTimeNoTime] <> '2014-11-12'
   set @rowCount = @@rowcount;
End
```